# How do i turn a list of lists into a simple list

Tags: python

I want to convert this list

```
myList = [[a], [b], [c]]
```

Into this list

```
cleaned_list = [a, b, c]
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: First, consider whether you can fix the code that created `myList`, so that you can get that result directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
my_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']]
cleaned_list = []
for x in my_list:
    for y in x:
        cleaned_list.append(y)
print(cleaned_list)
```

Also there is another solution:

```py
my_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']]
cleaned_list = [y for x in my_list for y in x]
```

These solutions also work for sublists with many elements.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a simple list comprehension:

```py
cleaned_list =  [i[0] for i in myList]
```

Comment: Note that this only works for single element sublists

Comment: The answer was provided according with the OP.

Comment: The OP gives no definition for any of the variables. `a = 1,2,3` would be completely valid and not work for the above answer.

Comment: Of course it would, on OP it states that the result should be `cleaned_list = [a, b, c]` each variable should not be flatted, so if `b = 10` and `c = 20` result would be: `[(1, 2, 3), 10, 20]`

Comment: *"Of course it would"*. You should really try to run that code first. With `a = 1,2,3`, `b = 10` and `c=20` you get an error since you'll be trying to subscript an int. Even if `b` and `c` are defined as tuples the output will be `[1,10,20]` since you'll only ever take the first element for each iteration.

Comment: Have you read the OP ? he's trying to convert `[[a], [b], [c]]` into `[a, b, c]`

Comment: I did read the OP and nowhere do I see them say they are single element sublists. Without a full working example you need to take the code as a rough guideline and not make large assumptions. This is evident by the fact that it now appears OP did indeed want support for multi element sublists.